# Angular Ionic 4 How to pass a Variable from page.html to page.ts

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I try to receive a Variable in my 'detail.page.ts'  from my 'list.page.html'

In 'list.page.html'  I have a list:

```html
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" href="details?Reihe={{item.ThemaNr}}">
      <ion-icon name="albums" slot="start" [style.color] ="item.Farbe"></ion-icon>
      {{item.Name}}
      <ion-icon name="list" slot="end"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

In my 'detail.page.ts' I want to fetch my JSON-Data like this:

```js
loadData() {
    let data:Observable<any>;
    data = this.http.get('https://myURL/mydata.json.php?Reihe= ( and here should be something like: --get."Reihe".from.my.html-page-- to get my ID) ');
    data.subscribe(result => {
      this.details = result;
    })
  }
```

(Hint: Would be even better if there is a "if(isset($_GET['Reihe']))" before  (like in PHP))

How could I manage/implement this ??  Sorry, I'm new in Ionic  for 4 days.
Big thanx for any ideas!

Regards, Estebu

---

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.15 (C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.8
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.2

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.8.1
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:

NodeJS : v13.5.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.13.4
   OS     : Windows 10

Comment: check this answer. [link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-pass-data-to-another-page/119413/3)

Comment: If you are showing the details in list.page.html, it is better you write the get code in list.ts.

Comment: No, I want to show the details in details.page.html

Answer (score 1):

Ionic 4 uses Angular's router. You can add a parameter to your details page:

```
{ path: 'details/:reihe', ... }
```

Access the parameter using `ActivatedRoute`:

```
constructor (
  private route: ActivatedRoute
) {
  let reihe = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('reihe');
}
```

Pass the parameter using `routerLink`:

```
<ion-item ... [routerLink]="['/details', item.ThemaNr]">
```

See the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters) for more info.

Comment: Thanx for Your help! But this is a little less information for me.  -- Where (in which different pages) exactly did I have to insert Your code?  -- What means the '...'  in { path: 'details/:reihe', ... } what should I write there?  --  I want to receive the get-parameter into the details.page.ts  cause I need it to do the JSON request . Thatswhy I can't pass the parameter (using routerLink) NOT in an <ion-item>  --   or am I fail at all??

Comment: I need the parameter from list.page.html  to -> details.page.ts

Comment: See [this sample](https://github.com/rveerd/ionic4-sample-router) based on the "sidemenu" starter template. Check out `app-routing.module.ts` and the list and detail pages. But you should really read some guides or documentation.